# Opening and closing an external page in a cordova application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

We have a cordova app which needs to run on both iOS and Android. In this app, we need to open a webpage so that the user can login securely and then come back to the app with a generated token. We've looked at the inappbrowser plugin which allows us to open the system browser like this : `window.open("http://loginWebsite", "_system");` and then we come back to the app with a custom URI scheme.

My problem with this is the page appears to stay open in the browser after the app is reoppened. On iOS it only leaves the last one open but on android it opens a new tab every single time, leaving them all open.

An alternate solution is to use the inappbrowser like so: `window.open("http://loginWebsite", "_blank");` but this appears to give our developper team the possibility to inject code with executeScript in the login or credit card pages we would use. This kind of defeats the purpose of having our login be separate our app.

Are there any solutions or other options ? If possible we would rather have the login be completely separate but having an app leave a bunch of tabs open seems weird.

Thanks